# Check and redirect to log in before checkout redirecting on wrong URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and I have created a login and register page. I am not using any plugin for this.

My issue is,  I have to check and redirect to log in before checkout I refer to this code([WooCommerce check and redirect to login before checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477504/woocommerce-check-and-redirect-to-login-before-checkout))

I am using the below code

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in() {
  $pageid = 10; // your checkout page id
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid)) {
    $url = add_query_arg(
      'redirect_to',
      get_permalink($pagid),
      site_url('/my-account/') // your my acount url
    );
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
  }
}
```

but when I click Proceed to checkout then I am getting the URL like

```
http://examle.com/my-account/?redirect_to=http://example.com/index.php/checkout/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in two steps.

*If the user goes to checkout and is not logged in*, he is redirected to the **my-account** page for login or registration.

```
// if the user is not logged in, return him to login before checkout
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() ) {
        $url = site_url('/my-account/');
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

After login or registration, *if the cart is not empty*, the user is redirected to checkout.

```
// redirect to checkout after login (or registration)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'redirect_after_login_or_registration_to_checkout_page' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_after_login_or_registration_to_checkout_page' );
function redirect_after_login_or_registration_to_checkout_page() {
    // only if the cart is not empty
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        return wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' );
    } else {
        return home_url();
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added both codes in the function.php. URL issue got shorted. Now I am getting the correct URL (http://examle.com/my-account). But now my issue is, I added the 404 pages on my website, and the above URL showing 404. Do I need to create a login page?

Comment: Ok. So I found the issue, instead of this URL examle.com/my-account I have to use examle.com/index.php/my-account

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897369/how-to-separate-the-login-and-register-page-and-access-using-shortcode

Comment: @Vdgaetango, Can you help me with the above link? Please