# Redirect unlogged users to My account if accessing checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My desired sequence would be:

User Checkout > Check login >

Proceed to checkout if logged in.
Redirect to login/register page if not logged in > proceed to the checkout page.
I have added below code in my active theme's function.php file but still having same problem

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_if_logged_in' );
function check_if_logged_in() {
    $pageid = 817; // your checkout page id

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( $pageid ) ) {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink( $pageid ),
            site_url( '/my-account/' ) // your my acount url
        );

        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Is your checkout page id really 817?

Comment: And for me your code makes not really a sense. Where you got it from? When should a user get redirect? With your code he always get's redirected on every page if it would be correct.

Comment: yes my page id is 817 and i find this code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477504/woocommerce-check-and-redirect-to-login-before-checkout this post

Comment: @Mr.Jo So I want:

-If Customer goes to checkout
-If Customer is Logged In, continue to checkout. If not logged in, go to a page with login and register forms.
-Once in this page, if customer logs in or register, continue to Checkout.

Comment: Please check my answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect_action' );
function template_redirect_action() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            wc_get_checkout_url(),
            get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) )
        );

        wp_safe_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: i am getting error " This page doesn't seem to exist.
It looks like the link pointing here was faulty. Maybe try searching?" and url as https://IP/?page_id=817

Comment: In this case there must be something wrong with your WooCommerce installation. Normally this option returns the correct page id and permalink will give the url. I've tested it on a fresh WooCommerce shop. And also I'm not redirecting with a page attribute. Maybe you still have your old snippet somewhere?

Comment: but when i perform checkout operation after log in it works fine.

Comment: Try updating your permalinks in WordPress again and verifiy that you've select the correct page for your checkout in WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced.

Comment: when i change page id with title like this "IP/checkout/" then it redirects to login page means it is working with page title.

Comment: Then there must be something strange since this is normal WC / WP functionality which is even better to use since the page id can change sometimes but if it works for you, you can use the pase id.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a redirect to my-admin when user is not logged in as follows:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'unlogged_user_checkout_redirect' );
function unlogged_user_checkout_redirect() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I tried the same code but it's redirecting like https://IP/?page_id=817